# Secure HTTP headers

Tags: http, webserver

In [this article](http://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/), the example shows

```
... HttpOnly;Secure
```

However, a check on my server response show

```
... Secure;HttpOnly
```

This may be a stupid question but, does the order matter?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750330/does-the-order-of-headers-in-an-http-response-ever-matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [RFC 6265 section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2), the individual attributes of the Set-Cookie header are processed in whatever order they're found, and the [Secure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.5) and [HttpOnly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.6) attributes are simply used to set discrete values with no reference or relation between the two:

> 8. If the cookie-attribute-list contains an attribute with an
>    attribute-name of "Secure", set the cookie's secure-only-flag to
>    true.  Otherwise, set the cookie's secure-only-flag to false.
> 9. If the cookie-attribute-list contains an attribute with an
>    attribute-name of "HttpOnly", set the cookie's http-only-flag to
>    true.  Otherwise, set the cookie's http-only-flag to false.

So, no, according to the RFC the order they're listed in doesn't matter.  Each will set a single flag, regardless of whether the other is absent, present, or in a varying order.

I've also never heard of an implementation that cared about the order (while I'm sure *something, somewhere, somehow,* gets this wrong - I wouldn't worry about it).

Note that this is a slightly different question than [the one @BadSkillz referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750330/does-the-order-of-headers-in-an-http-response-ever-matter) in his comment - that has to do with the order of headers; this has to do with the order of fields within a particular header.

...

*Completely* coincidentally, I [enabled Secure and HttpOnly flags for F5 ASM cookies](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/13000/700/sol13787.html?sr=45119777) on one of my systems today.  The F5 ASM will tack two cookies on to help do it's WAF-y magic.  As soon as I enabled it I tested and these are the cookies they sent (... for width):

```
Set-Cookie: TS01145f87=01ca34131874c763...6207; Path=/; Secure; HTTPOnly 
Set-Cookie: TS013fdbf2=01ca341318b0cba9...b198; path=/ui/; HTTPonly; Secure
```

So for two cookies set by one piece of software with one configuration point, it ended up with different orders for the attributes.